# Parse XML Response from ITIS using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 30k species names. I'm trying to access the ITIS API via Excel VBA in order to get the authorship of all these names, and copy them over to the spreadsheet.

As an example, I access the following link:
https://www.itis.gov/ITISWebService/services/ITISService/getITISTermsFromScientificName?srchKey=Nicrophorus%20americanus

which returns this response:

```
<ns:getITISTermsFromScientificNameResponse xmlns:ns="http://itis_service.itis.usgs.gov">
    <ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://data.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd" xmlns:ax23="http://metadata.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd" xmlns:ax26="http://itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:SvcItisTermList">
        <ax21:itisTerms xsi:type="ax21:SvcItisTerm">
            <ax21:tsn>200997</ax21:tsn>
            <ax21:author>Olivier, 1790</ax21:author>
            <ax21:commonNames>American burying beetle</ax21:commonNames>
            <ax21:commonNames>giant carrion beetle</ax21:commonNames>
            <ax21:nameUsage>valid</ax21:nameUsage>
            <ax21:scientificName>Nicrophorus americanus</ax21:scientificName>
        </ax21:itisTerms>
        <ax21:requestedName>Nicrophorus americanus</ax21:requestedName>
    </ns:return>
</ns:getITISTermsFromScientificNameResponse>
```

I am using the following VBA code to parse the XML and copy the authorship to the spreadsheet.

```
Dim lastrow, genus, species, counter, i
lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    
i = 0

For i = 0 To lastrow - 1
   Cells(i + 2, 6).Select
   genus = Cells(i + 2, 6).Value
   Cells(i + 2, 8).Select
   species = Cells(i + 2, 8).Value
        
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim XmlResponse As String
    Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        
    If genus <> "" Then
        Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        sURL = "https://www.itis.gov/ITISWebService/services/ITISService/getITISTermsFromScientificName?srchKey=" & genus & "%20" & species
        'MsgBox sURL

        oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
        oXMLHTTP.Send

        XmlResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText
        'MsgBox XmlResponse
                            
         Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
         XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='http://itis_service.itis.usgs.gov' xmlns:ax21='http://data.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd' xmlns:ax23='http://metadata.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd' xmlns:ax26='http://itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"
          
        If Not XDoc.LoadXML(XmlResponse) Then
            Err.Raise XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , XDoc.parseError.reason
        End If
            
        Set xNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:getITISTermsFromScientificNameResponse/ns:return/ax21:itisTerms/author")
        'MsgBox xNode.Text
            
        Cells(i + 2, 11).Select
        Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = Trim(xNode)
```

Everything seems to work until I get to the "Set Xnode =" Line, which seems to return "Nothing". And the script throws a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" when it tries to execute the last line of the code where it copes the author value to the spreadsheet cell. The XmlResponse does return the requested information just fine. So I think my problem lies in parsing the returned xml response and getting the value from the "author" item.  Do I have the XDoc.SelectSingleNode syntax correct for the returned xml in this case (it would seem I do not, given the error)? Any thoughts on how I should modify this to make it work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possibly changing `... = ".../author"` to `... = ".../ax21:author"`?

Comment: @T.M. I added that in, completely overlooked that I was missing the prefix on the author.  If I do a MsgBox xNode.Text, it looks like the value it contains now is the authorship I'm looking for, but then when I go to write it to the worksheet cell, it now throws a "Runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error, again, on the last line of the script, Cells(i+1,11).Value = xNode.  Any ideas why this would occur?

Comment: @T.M.  I figured it out.  I needed to have `Cells(i+2, 11).Value = xNode.Text` in order for it to work.